# Creating a linear gradient with an angle

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I have design specs that call for a gradient like this

[image]

I figured out how to do the slanted line and the color shift, but am having trouble accomplishing both in the same linear gradient property.

```
background: linear-gradient(90deg, #007bff, #0C4078); // color is right 
background: linear-gradient(178deg, white 50%, white 50%, #007bff 50%, #007bff 40%); // line angle is right
```

How can I make my linear gradient look like the spec?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to consider multiple background:

```css
.box {
 height:200px;
 background: 
   linear-gradient(to bottom right,#fff 49%,transparent 50%) top/100% 30%,
   linear-gradient(to right, #007bff, #0C4078);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

In case you want transparency you can use `clip-path` with one background:

```css
.box {
 height:200px;
 background:linear-gradient(to right, #007bff, #0C4078);
 -webkit-clip-path:polygon(0 30%,0 100%, 100% 100%,100% 0);
 clip-path:polygon(0 30%,0 100%, 100% 100%,100% 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Or `mask`

```css
.box {
 height:200px;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #007bff, #0C4078);
 -webkit-mask:
  linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49%,white 50%) top/100% 30% no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(white,white) bottom/100% 70% no-repeat;
 mask:
  linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49%,white 50%) top/100% 30% no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(white,white) bottom/100% 70% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

---

Here is another way if you want transparency and better support than `clip-path`/`mask`:

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: skewY(-5deg);
  transform-origin: right;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #007bff, #0C4078);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed. =]